# Is it possible to set an image on a Reporting Services Report from memory?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting, localreport

I am trying to figure out a way to programatically set an image on a Visual Studio Report where the image doesn't come from a file or from the database but from the running application.

My best guess is to somehow subvert the Embedded or Database Source types but I have been unable to figure out how to do this.

Do I really want to do this?  Yes.  The images are not in the database and can't be access via the file system for security reasons.  I plan to Render the report directly to a PDF file stream to hopefully keep the memory footprint down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a revised solution:
[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

Comment: How would I then go about setting that image on my report?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image temporarily in the database after the user selects it from your app... in a table used for just that, clear out the table periodically, if you never really want to save this image.  Then display in the report by passing the imageID for the table; based on what you said above it sounds like you know how to display an image saved in your database but if not I can give you a tutorial link.